# Overridden __setitem__ call works in serial but breaks in apply_async call

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, overriding, python-multiprocessing, apply-async

I've been fighting with this problem for some time now and I've finally managed to narrow down the issue and create a minimum working example.

The summary of the problem is that I have a class that inherits from a `dict` to facilitate parsing of misc. input files. I've overridden the the `__setitem__` call to support recursive indexing of sections in our input file (e.g. `parser['some.section.variable']` is equivalent to `parser['some']['section']['variable']`). This has been working great for us for over a year now, but we just ran into an issue when passing these `Parser` classes through a `multiprocessing.apply_async` call.

Show below is the minimum working example - obviously the `__setitem__` call isn't doing anything special, but it's important that it accesses some class attribute like `self.section_delimiter` - this is where it breaks. It doesn't break in the initial call or in the serial function call. But when you call the `some_function` (which doesn't do anything either) using `apply_async`, it crashes.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

class Parser(dict):

    def __init__(self, file_name : str = None):
        print('\t__init__')
        super().__init__()
        self.section_delimiter = "."
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('\t__setitem__')
        self.section_delimiter
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
           
def some_function(parser):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Initialize creation/setting")
    parser = Parser()
    parser['x'] = 1

    print("Single serial call works fine")
    some_function(parser)

    print("Parallel async call breaks on line 16?")
    pool = mp.Pool(1)
    for i in range(1):
        pool.apply_async(some_function, (parser,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If you run the code below, you'll get the following output

```sh
Initialize creation/setting
    __init__
    __setitem__
Single serial call works fine
Parallel async call breaks on line 16?
    __setitem__
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ijw/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/ijw/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ijw/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/ijw/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 354, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "test_apply_async.py", line 13, in __setitem__
    self.section_delimiter
AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'section_delimiter'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I spent considerable time tracking down this bug and reproducing a minimal example. I would love to not only fix it, but clearly fill some gap in my understanding on how these `apply_async` and inheritance/overridden methods interact.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you very much!

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cause

The cause of the problem is that `multiprocessing` serializes and deserializes your `Parser` object to move its data across process boundaries. This is done using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#). By default [pickle does not call `__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances) when deserializing classes. Because of this `self.section_delimiter` is not set when the deserializer calls `__setitem__()` to restore the items in your dictionary and you get the error:

> AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'section_delimiter'

Using just pickle and no multiprocessing gives the same error:

```
import pickle

parser = Parser()
parser['x'] = 1

data = pickle.dumps(parser)
copy = pickle.loads(data) # Same AttributeError here
```

Deserialization will work for an object with no items and the value of `section_delimiter` will be restored:

```
import pickle

parser = Parser()
parser.section_delimiter = "|"

data = pickle.dumps(parser)
copy = pickle.loads(data)

print(copy.section_delimiter) # Prints "|"
```

So in a sense you are just unlucky that pickle calls `__setitem__()` before it restores the rest of the state of your `Parser`.

#### Workaround

You can work around this by setting `section_delimiter` in `__new__()` and telling pickle what arguments to pass to `__new__()` by implementing `__getnewargs__()`:

```
def __new__(cls, *args):
    self = super(Parser, cls).__new__(cls)
    self.section_delimiter = args[0] if args else "."
    return self

def __getnewargs__(self):
    return (self.section_delimiter,)
```

`__getnewargs__()` returns a tuple of arguments. Because `section_delimiter` is set in `__new__()`, it is no longer necessary to set it in `__init__()`.

This is the code of your `Parser` class after the change:

```
class Parser(dict):

    def __init__(self, file_name : str = None):
        print('\t__init__')
        super().__init__()

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        self = super(Parser, cls).__new__(cls)
        self.section_delimiter = args[0] if args else "."
        return self

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (self.section_delimiter,)
 
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('\t__setitem__')
        self.section_delimiter
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

#### Simpler solution

The reason pickle calls `__setitem__()` on your `Parser` object is because it *is* a dictionary. If your `Parser` is just a class that happens to implement `__setitem__()` and `__getitem__()` and *has* a dictionary to implement those calls then pickle will not call `__setitem__()` and serialization will work with no extra code:

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self, file_name : str = None):
        print('\t__init__')
        self.dict = { }
        self.section_delimiter = "."

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('\t__setitem__')
        self.section_delimiter
        self.dict[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dict[key]
```

So if there is no other reason for your `Parser` to be a dictionary, I would just not use inheritance here.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you @peter! The appreciate the details of the underlying cause and two solution suggestions. I think either will work well, and I will just need to consider the implications of each. Thank you again!

Comment: I think if possible you should try to get rid of the inheritance relationship between the builtin type `dict` and `Parser`. As I see it that is the root cause of your problem. It may be a bit more difficult initially but the resulting code is much simpler and more maintainable then if you use `__new__()` etc.

Comment: Yes I definitely see how that could be a simpler/better solution. However, in this case the `Parser` makes use of calling all kinds of `dict` functionality (keys, items, values, pop, + all dunder methods, etc.) Of course, I could just implement each of these, but the `__new__` solution is working well, and I'm not convinced it's worth it to switch over. I assume this is what you mean when you say "more difficult initially" though!